# Can not send emails with delimiter in local part (Postfix + LDAP)

Tags: postfix, ldap

I just moved my mail server. With the move, an update from Postfix 3.1 to 3.4 happened (Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04).

On the Postfix 3.1 install, I was able to send and receive emails with the delimiter `+` in the local part. The same config with Postfix 3.4 lets me *receive* emails with `+` in the local part but when I try *sending* an email with `+` (say, e.g. me+test@mydomain.tld) the server returns

```
5.7.1 <holger+testmail@[redacted]>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user
```

In my *main.cf*, the virtual maps are mapped as follows:

```
virtual_alias_maps = 
  hash:/etc/aliases,
  proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-forwarding.cf, 
  proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-virtual-maps.cf
```

The sender restrictions are:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = unionmap:{proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf,pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_login_override.pcre}
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
  reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, 
  permit_sasl_authenticated, 
  reject_non_fqdn_sender, 
  reject_unknown_sender_domain, 
  reject_unlisted_sender,
  reject_unauth_pipelining, 
  reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, 
  reject_unknown_client_hostname,
```

And, of course, the delimiter is set:

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

*ldap-forwarding.cf*:

```
version = 3
server_host = localhost
server_port = 389

bind_dn = [redacted]
bind_pw = [redacted]
search_base = ou=Users,dc=[redacted]
query_filter = (&(|(uid=%u)(mail=%s)(mailAlternateAddress=%s))(objectClass=qmailUser)(accountStatus=forward))
result_attribute = mailForwardingAddress
```

*ldap_aliases.cf*:

```
version = 3
server_host = localhost
server_port = 389

bind_dn = [redacted]
bind_pw = [redacted]
search_base = ou=Users,dc=[redacted]
query_filter = (&(|(uid=%u)(mailAlternateAddress=%s)(mail=%s))(objectClass=qmailUser)(|(accountStatus=active)(accountStatus=shared)(accountStatus=forward)))
result_attribute = uid
result_format = %u
```

*ldap-domains.cf*:

```
version = 3
server_host = localhost
server_port = 389

bind_dn = [redacted]
bind_pw = [redacted]
search_base = ou=DNS,ou=System,dc=[redacted]
query_filter = (associatedDomain=%s)
result_attribute = associatedDomain
```

*ldap-virtual-maps.cf*:

```
version = 3
server_host = localhost
server_port = 389

bind_dn = [redacted]
bind_pw = [redacted]
search_base = ou=Users,dc=[redacted]
query_filter = (&(|(mail=%s)(mailAlternateAddress=%s))(|(accountStatus=active)(accountStatus=shared)))
result_attribute = mailMessageStore
```

I can't seem to find the issue. Any hints are highly appreciated. Also, if any further information is needed, I am happy to add it.

**UPDATE 1, 2021-01-27, 21:24 CET:**
Ok, I found what breaks it in the first place:

```
unionmap:{proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf,pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_login_override.pcre}
```

Changing this to

```
proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
```

lets me send mails with `+` in it again. Question is now, is this supposed to happen? And if so, how could I define exceptions to the general rule?

Comment: It seems `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` is triggered, it usually displays such error message. Remeber, `smtpd_sender_login_maps` is a relation of envelope from email to authenticated user name. Postfix queries this map (union of `ldap-aliases.cf`, `sender_login_override.pcre`) with email address specified in "MAIL FROM" in the smtp session as a key and it must have in return all SASL logins that are permitted to use it. What your union map returns if queired with `holger+testmail@[redacted]`? Try checking with `postmap`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

`postmap` doesn't return the mapping, but this is also true for the old server, interestingly enough.

It turns out, `unionmap` causes the issue. I just don't understand why.

Comment: It seems unionmap doesn't know about delimiter. I haven't that map. However, you can try to write overrides that cope with delimiter themselves, not relying on map to do it.